# Error:MetaGraphDef associated with tags 'serve' could not be found in SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this error

```
RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags 'serve' could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
available_tags: [{'train', 'serve'}]
```

I did `saved_model_cli show --dir ./`, I got

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'train, serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:
```

My source code is

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],'../export_dir/0/')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
    with tf.gfile.GFile('./frozen.pb', "wb") as f:
        f.write(graph.SerializeToString())
```

When I search this problem solution, I saw "Use [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING]", but I cannnot solve this problem...

Comment: What are the files inside `../export_dir/0/`? Also try to give complete path and try replacing `[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING]` with `["serve"]`.

Comment: There are 'saved_model.pb' and 'variables' in `../export_dir/0/`. When I replaced ["serve"], this error was not change

Comment: And 'flatbuffer.py', 'variables.data-00000-of-00001' and 'variables.index' in 'variables'.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is telling you that the output tensor name you specified is not found in the saved model.

If all your installations go well, you should have access to use the `saved_model_cli` handy from anywhere in the terminal.

To see your output tensor names, simply run the command

`saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/saved/model --all`

You can also check for more reference [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#apis_to_build_and_load_a_savedmodel)

Comment: when I run this nothing is output at all. Why would that be?

Comment: you used wrong python.
try 
```python saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/saved/model --all```
or 
```python3 saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/saved/model --all```

Comment: That is because there is no graph definition. Go the other way round and try an example of a saved_model (a link is provided in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have what is called a **frozen graph**. Those cannot be converted, nor do they have a graph definition. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937580/1885934) discussion for a detailed answer.

For comparison with a **saved model** (with graph definition) where a conversion works, see this [hello_world](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/tree/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/hello_world/train) example from Tensorflow Lite Micro. When you either train the model yourself based on the provided Jupyter notebook or download the [hello_world.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/micro/hello_world_2020_12_28.zip) you get ***saved_model.pb***. Enter the directory where this file is located, `models/model` and type

```
saved_model_cli show --dir ./ --all
```

then you get a long list of information. Or either

```
saved_model_cli show --dir=./
```

you get

```
The given SavedModel contains the following tag-sets: 'serve'
```